# How to make Bootstrap 3 Style Framed image in iOS

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, uiimage

I want to make 3 image effect is iOS that match Bootstrap effects:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

I figured out rounded corners & circle - but..the framed one is stumping me.

"img-thumbnail" - makes a thin grey rounded rectangle frame around the image.

How can this be done?
Any library that does it?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple. It's just css borders. Here is the original class code from the bootstrap source.

```
.img-thumbnail {
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 4px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: yeah - but i need this effect on a iOS UIImage - using object-c - not css - thats the issue. thx anyways